# Concurrent row updates. Hibernate 5 / Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I need to gracefully handle multiple update requests for the api.

For example: I have two entities: **A** and **B**(**A** to **B** relationship is OneToMany) and two endpoints: *Delete **A*** and *Delete **B***

*Delete B* is just deleting entity by Id

*Delete A* delete A with cascade deletion B

- Select A
- Select List by A
- Delete B
- Delete A

I guess optimistic locking won't help here and I need pessimistic locking, but all my attempts to use them lead to deadlocks (when selecting data to create response). And I assume that's not about transactions isolation level, because they only isolates reading.

Now I am getting `StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected 1` for delete A request.

Is it possible to handle both requests without rejecting?